# Unable to drag drop to ZIP

Tags: drag-and-drop, drag, winzip

I'm trying to drag txt and png files to one of the zip folders I have on my desktop but it doesn't work. Can easily drag these files to a regular folder though.Windows 10. Please help.

Comment: Maybe this question is for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Copy to notepad save as `7z.bat`

Note: It cannot be operated on the desktop, C drive root directory, etc.

```
@ECHO OFF
@REM @Author: xianghongai@gmail.com
title Drag, Zip

7z a -tzip  "%~1.zip" "%~1" -xr!node_modules

echo :)
echo Completed!
echo Press any key to exit.
pause >nul
exit
```